# Spring Security /j_spring_security_check Not Found 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Here is my WebAppInitializer:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Here is my Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signup", "/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/error").permitAll()
                .and().httpBasic();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

And this is my login.html (example html from thymeleaf):

```
<form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post">
  <label for="j_username">Username</label>:
  <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" /> <br />

  <label for="j_password">Password</label>:
  <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" /> <br />

  <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

When i click on login, this error appears:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /j_spring_security_check. Reason:

    Not Found
```

How can i get rid of this error? I googled a lot, but no success yet. (Yes I do not use any xml.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have created this, and it works now:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

This activates the SpringSecurityFilterChain apperently.

I also had to switch from @EnableWebSecurity to **@EnableWebMvcSecurity** because of an CSRF error. As in the spring doc is written:

> ...The reason is that Spring Security is protecting against CSRF
>   attakcks and there is no CSRF token include in our request. Update our
>   configuration to use the @EnableWebMvcSecurity annotation which will
>   do the same as @EnableWebMvcSecurity and provide integration with
>   Spring MVC. Among other things, it will ensure our CSRF Token is
>   included in our forms automatically when using Thymleaf 2.1+ or Spring
>   MVC taglibs...

Also Thanks M. Deinum for his comment. Spring has recently switched the /j_spring_security_check /j_password /j_username to  /login /password /username apparently.

Comment: Alternative to the above is to initialize the filter programmatically. IE: FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*"); To me this approach makes more sense or you could add it to your application xml. Does the same thing, having an empty class just seems wrong and will probably be deleted in the future if not commented due to no references existing.

Answer (score 19):

Can be version issue if you are using spring 4.X then

> a.) login url = /login 
>   b.) logout url = /logout

where as in case spring 3.X

> a.) login url = /j_spring_security_check
>   b.) logout url = /j_spring_security_logout

Comment: I already have a path /login in my application, wouldn't that cause any problem?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this issue when disable csrf. I tried to specify the `loginProcessingUrl` explicitly and it worked perfectly!

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
   httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
   httpSecurity.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login-url");
}
```

Please notice that:

1. This url only allows `HTTP POST` method.
2. Other default important urls in `Spring Security` are: 1. `/login`: return the default login form 2. `/logout`

My `Spring Security` version is 4.0.3.RELEASE

`P/S`: my answer may not be related directly to the question but I think it can help someone who is new to `Spring Security` like me