# Java config /j_spring_security_check not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, http-status-code-404, j-security-check

I'm a noob to Spring framework.

Trying to configure security options for the app. I have following as my (xml-less) security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("accountService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**" ).hasRole( "Admin" )
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .loginProcessingUrl( "/j_spring_security_check" )
            .failureUrl( "/loginfailed" )
            .permitAll()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}

}
```

It displays the login page but when I submit it throws me a `/j_spring_security_check Not Found` exception. Any help is much appreciated.

My web config is thus:

```
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup( ServletContext servletContext ) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register( MvcServletConfig.class );
    applicationContext.register( SecurityConfig.class );

    //Add the servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet( "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet( applicationContext ) );
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));
    servlet.addMapping( "/" );
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup( 1 );
}
}
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469834/spring-security-j-spring-security-check-not-found-404 ?

Comment: Try removing `/` from `j_spring_security_check` or create URL with absolute path of context & then `/j_spring_security_check`.

Comment: @BretC - I did try that and it helped to a degree, but I got stuck soon with `j_spring_security_logout`. I've updated the answer now.
@OO7 - Thanks but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my WebConfig as thus

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[ ] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[ ] { AppConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[ ]{ MvcServletConfig.class };
}
}
```

Added a `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` as following:

```
public class SecurityInitialiser extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

My `configure()` method override in `SecurityConfig` now looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage( "/" )
                .loginProcessingUrl( "/j_spring_security_check" )
                .defaultSuccessUrl( "/hello" )
                .failureUrl( "/loginfailed" )
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl( "/j_spring_security_logout" )
                .logoutSuccessUrl( "/" )
                .invalidateHttpSession( true )
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage( "/WEB-INF/pages/403.jsp" )
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

Hope this helps someone! Thanks to all who chipped in their suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form)

`.loginPage("/")` overrides the url that you have to submit to.

Probably what you want is `.loginPage("/j_spring_security_check")`

Comment: Not really as that's how the landing page is set in the servlet mappings. Instead `.loginProcessingUrl( "/j_spring_security_check" )` worked for me.