# How to change Login URL in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

I created an API that provides User authentication and it's login operation is handled on default **'/login'** path  by Spring Security.

I want to change this path to **'api/v1/login'**.

this is my security config :

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/user/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/reset-password").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/reset-password").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/user").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/roles").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionHandlerFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUserDetailService));
```

I have added this line to change it :

```
.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login")
```

But it is still working under **'/login'** path.

"/api/v1/login" return 404.

Is there any way to change it ?

Spring Boot Version : 2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: .loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login") will override the /login post url to /api/v1/login where you will submit the credentials

Comment: I am sending post request via postman,it doesn't override  it, still working for '/login'.

Comment: Post the complete url that you are trying and can you also share the screenshot of postman

Comment: @kakabali https://image.ibb.co/ksihH7/Screenshot_from_2018_03_31_09_20_21.png

Comment: Can you also check if your urls under `/api/**` are all secured?

If yes then try removing the security from `/api/v1/login` and add permitAll() configuration to this url

Comment: try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27471722/2600196

Comment: also if you can check changing - `@EnableWebSecurity` to `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` as it has been asked by the person on that

Comment: as you have shared in the screenshot that it is showing **404**, but looks like your `/api/v1/login` is getting redirected to `/login` and in your application it is no more present because you override it, I can see in the response that it is giving `"path":"/login"`, in the case of `/api/v1/login` it should have given `"path":"/api/v1/login"`

Comment: don't you think like this?

Comment: @kakabali Yes it redirects  but why I cant reach service? whereas  it is working for **'/login'** while I getting this error.

Comment: I have added update to the answer please check

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function `.loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login")`, specifies the URL to validate the credentials, the URL to validate username and password.

It will only override url to `/api/v1/login` of **POST** type, not **GET**

It will not pass the request to Spring MVC and your controller

For additional customization you can have a look through `FormLoginConfigurer`

**UPDATE v1**

Can you also check if your urls under `/api/**` are all secured?

If yes then try removing the security from `/api/v1/login` and add permitAll() configuration to this url

Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27471722/2600196. if it helps your scenario

**UPDATE v2 - this helped in the case here**

you were not sending the username and password correctly and for that to work refer the things below, in your it was showing up `BadCredentialsException`. I enabled debug on the application and was able to figure that out.

you need to post the parameters to the url - http://localhost:8080/api/v1/login as below (have also attached the image, screenshot of postman):-

headers:
`Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

parameters in key value pairs(not in json format, please refer the image):

```
username=player3
password=pass3
```

[image]

Above you can the response coming up from the index.html like below:-

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/other.html">test static resource</a>
```

Which you also need to customize.

**For Sending the JSON request for username and password, the changes that will work easily for you will be:-**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/user/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/reset-password").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/reset-password").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/user").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/roles").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        //.and()
        //.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login") // not required any more
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionHandlerFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilter(jwtAuthorizationFilter())
        .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUserDetailService));
    
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // its required for h2-console

}

public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter() throws Exception {
    JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/login");
    return jwtAuthenticationFilter;
}
```

And the code `.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login")` not required anymore

Further you need to add the success and the failure urls to the application, and to make your login url to fetch json based user credentials, you need to follow up and need to do some more stuff, some useful reference for that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19501060/2600196

Answer (score 6):

You are [extending org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html&ved=2ahUKEwijoezvvZjaAhVKrY8KHbDiCjAQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw0-KS3g97LIfu9ykggCwbtH) which itself [extendsorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html&ved=2ahUKEwjx_eDBvpjaAhUNTY8KHU0ED60QFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1GgCdSX-byuAFcYQI0ZjI-). In this last class, there is a setter called

> setFilterProcessesUrl

which is intended to do just this:

> setFilterProcessesUrl
>
> public void setFilterProcessesUrl(String filterProcessesUrl)
>
> Sets the URL that determines if authentication is required
>
> Parameters: filterProcessesUrl

[This](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html) is the link to that javadoc section

So in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter you could do just like this:

```
@Bean 
public JWTAuthenticationFilter getJWTAuthenticationFilter() { 
    final JWTAuthenticationFilter filter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()); 
    filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/auth/login"); 
    return filter; 
}
```

And then in your configure method in the same class just reference it instead of creating new instance:

```
.addFilter(getJWTAuthenticationFilter
```